# FirebaseAdmin FirebaseApp Check if Firebase Instance exists

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a C# project that subscribes multiple Registrations to a Topic. Because of the nature of the project and the fact that you cant check to see how many people have already subscribed to a Topic I need to make the following Async Calls to the server:

**Subscribe Registrations**

```
TopicManagementResponse response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SubscribeToTopicAsync(registrationTokens, topic);
```

**Send message to Topic**

```
string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
```

**Unsubscribe Registrations**

```
TopicManagementResponse response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.UnsubscribeFromTopicAsync(registrationTokens, topic);
```

Because there are three calls I need to Create an Instance of the FirebaseApp using Credentials:

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(path),
});
```

BUT because the async posts return a "WaitingForActivation" response (yet it does correctly do what it is supposed to do) I cant Delete the Instance to move on to the next function as it throws an error as it cant re-create another FirebaseApp Instance - It fails if I give it a name so I cant use GetInstance(string name).

Am I missing something or is there another way to do this.

Here is an example of a subscribe function:

```
internal static async Task SubscribeToTopic(string path, string topic, string regID5, string regID)
{
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(path),
    });

    var registrationTokens = new List<string>()
    {
       regID5, regID
    };

    // Subscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens to the
    // topic

    try
    {
        TopicManagementResponse response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SubscribeToTopicAsync(registrationTokens, topic);

        using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/tokens.txt")))
        {
            sw.WriteLine($"{response.SuccessCount} tokens were subscribed successfully");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string myerror = ex.Message;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating firebase instance every time. so you need to create firebase instance in application start in global.asax file.